# Asp.net gridview horizontal layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gallery in gridview that show pictures from database.

I need to show the gridview in horizontal layout.

Right now the pictures are organized from up to down, 
How can i change the gridview so it will show the pictures from left to right in one row ?

html code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" class="GridView1" runat="server" Width="400px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="90px"
                    CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image_path" DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Pic/{0}" HeaderText="Images">
                <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px" />
            </asp:ImageField>               

        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

c# code:

```
 con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select image_path from tblImages", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView3.DataSource = dt;
    GridView3.DataBind();
```

con.Close();

Answer (score 5):

Use a `DataList` with [`RepeatDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) horizontal instead.

That works since you want to show a single column anyway.

```
<asp:DataList id="Images" 
       RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
       RepeatLayout="Table"
       RepeatColumns="0" runat="server">
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#aaaadd">
     </HeaderStyle>
     <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="Gainsboro">
     </AlternatingItemStyle>
     <HeaderTemplate>
        Images ...
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Image id="ProductImage"
             AlternatingText='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StringValue") %>'
             ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image_path","~/Images/{0}") %>' />
             runat="server"/>

     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, i put in the "ImageValue" my table db image_path column,
but the pictures are blank for some reason, what should i put in the "ImageValue" ?

    ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageValue") %>'

Comment: Have you looked the html source? What is the `src` of the images, are they correct?

Comment: @GiladAdar: right-click in your browser and choose _View Source_. Then search for the ID and look what ASP.NET has generated.

Comment: I hope its help, <img id="Images_ProductImage_1" src="images.jpg" />

Comment: dont forget its from my database. how can i proceed from here please ?

Comment: So i assume `images.jpg` is not the correct path to your image. What would be correct?

Comment: @GiladAdar: Edited my answer to provide a way assuming that your image is in a `Images` directory in the root folder(`~` will be replaced with the correct path) of your web-application.

Comment: Hi, thank you all, problem solved:  <img ID="imgField" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("images/{0}", Eval("Name")) %>' />

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                </asp:DetailsView>
```